# How to convert IList<string> to a string[] without using Linq

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0

I'm not sure what is the best way to convert an `IList<string>` (`IList` does not implement the ToArray property) to an `string[]` array.

I cannot use `Linq` because I'm compiling with .NET 2.0. Any ideas will be wellcome.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use [`ICollection<T>.CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0efx51xw.aspx):

```
string[] strings = new string[list.Count];
list.CopyTo(strings, 0);
```

I'm not quite sure if I understand the no-LINQ restriction though? It sounds like you would use `ToArray` if `IList<T>` had it. But it turns out it does because `IEnumerable<T>.ToArray` is an extension method defined on `IEnumerable<T>` of which `IList<T>` implements. So why don't you just use that?

Answer (score 4):

If you are forced to have IList, then to get an array...

```
IList list; 
var array = new List<string>(list).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 3):

ToArray is an extension method of IEnumerable, and IList implement IEnumerable. You can do it if you import that.

Answer (score 1):

One way or another, you are going to have to create an array and fill the contents of it with what is in the list.  This is the most straight forward way of doing it.

```
var arr = new string[Your_List.Count]

for(var ii = 0; ii < arr.Length; ii++){
   arr[ii] = Your_List[ii];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
 public static T[] ToArray<T>(this IList<T> list)  
    {  
        if (list is Array) return (T[]) list;  

        T[] retval = new T[list.Count];  
        for (int i = 0; i < retval.Length; i++)   
            retval[i] = list[i];  

        return retval;  
    }
```

Its only a rough .May be its help.